# Help me correct the sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

> Having recently been completely remodelled, they thought the house lacked charm.

According to the assignment this sentence is incorrect. But I can't figure our how. 
My best guess is to add of in-between lacked and charm so it reads, "lacked of charm"? But really I have no idea.

Comment: I don't see how this phrase is incorrect.

Comment: As a native speaker, it didn't immediately strike me as wrong either - I actually had to work harder to misinterpret it - but It perhaps implies that *they* have been completely remodelled, rather than *the house*?

Comment: @stevekeiretsu Yes, I'd say it does. _They_ is the subject of the sentence. A better way to express the idea would be "Although the house had recently been remodelled, they thought it lacked charm."

Comment: stevekeiretsu & @KateBunting
Thank you. Would never have been able to see it myself!

Comment: I would put "recently" after "remodelled".

Answer (score 2):

Your example is a textbook case of a [dangling modifier](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/dangling_modifiers_and_how_to_correct_them.html). The problem is that the subordinate clause of your sentence ("Having recently been completely remodeled") modifies the *subject* of the independent clause ("**they** thought the house lacked charm").

In other words, the sentence says that *they* have been completely remodeled, while the intent of the speaker was likely that *the house* was completely remodeled. Hence the error.

The most obvious way to fix the sentence is to rewrite it so that *the house* is the subject of the independent clause:

> Having recently been completely remodeled, the house lacked charm to them.

or make both clauses independent:

> Because the house has recently been completely remodeled, they thought it lacked charm.

Comment: Spot on. I didn't know such thing existed. +1